# java calling procedure of package no response

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have created an API  module of spring boot application to call stored procedure. When it comes to the implementation, stmt.execute cannot be called with no response. Would you please tell me which module or wayout to modify under my java environment is 1.8?

```java
int retVal = -1;
int errCode = -1;
String errText = null;
int outPos;
int pos = 0;
System.out.println("call 2");

String SQL_SELECT = "{call database_sid.test_pkg.get_pc_lue(?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DBC_URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
     CallableStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareCall(SQL_SELECT);
) {

    System.out.println("call db");

    preparedStatement.setString(++pos, "OFFER_TYPE");
    preparedStatement.setString(++pos, null); // acct srv limit

    preparedStatement.registerOutParameter(outPos = ++pos, Types.REF_CURSOR);
    preparedStatement.registerOutParameter(++pos, Types.INTEGER);
    preparedStatement.registerOutParameter(++pos, Types.INTEGER);
    preparedStatement.registerOutParameter(++pos, Types.VARCHAR);
    System.out.println("call 10");

    ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    System.out.println("call 11");
    while (resultSet.next()) {


        String value = resultSet.getString("LOOKUP_VALUE");
        String type = resultSet.getString("LOOKUP_TYPE");
        PcTblBPcLookUp obj = new PcTblBPcLookUp();
        obj.setLookUpValue(value);
        obj.setLookUpType(type);
        result.add(obj);
        System.out.println("call 1obecj1");
    }
    result.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
    System.out.println("call finish ");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("call error : " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: whats outcome, any error ?

Comment: quick question, what is your database

Comment: Oracle is my main database source. The outcome goes printing to message : call db  and no further actions

Comment: @ShaileshChandra Appears to be Oracle. `database_sid` No one else uses SID to identify databases.

Comment: If prints "call db", but not "call 10"??? Then it threw an exception, and you're not looking at where the `System.err` output goes. --- It's curious why `SQLException` is printed to `System.err`, while everything else is printed to `System.out`.

Comment: Do you mean adding try block at the section between “call db ” and “call 10”?

Comment: it's more than a decade since I used stored procedure with Java ref cursor, the reason I asked about DB is that I always faced issues with oracle ref cursor, so I always registered output type from oracle **OracleTypes.CURSOR**, can you try this,**preparedStatement.registerOutParameter(outPos = ++pos, OracleTypes.CURSOR);**

Comment: This ORAcle type is deprecated now

Comment: I guess package changed https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleTypes.html

Comment: and database_sid is your schema name, right ?

Comment: Then under java 1.8, what type should we use for output cursor?

Comment: I have posted an answer try that

Comment: Confirm.if my suggestion worked?

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute your stored procedure using execute and then you need to fetch your resultset from opsition registered for out parameter

```
preparedStatement.execute();

ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) preparedStatement.getObject(outPos);
```